# How big are the downloads for the Windows 8 Pro upgrade?

Tags: windows-8, download

I have a relatively slow Internet connection (1.2 Mbps) and I am planning to purchase the Windows 8 Pro upgrade online. However, I can only guess how much data actually needs to be downloaded by the Upgrade Assistant - I couldn't find the sizes anywhere on Microsoft's website or the Windows 8 site. By determining the actual size of the download, I can plan my time accordingly, since we're likely talking about a few hours here.

In particular, I'm asking about the 64-bit edition - but I decided to make this question generic just in case someone wonders how big the 32-bit edition is (the sizes of the ISO files that I downloaded for the Consumer Preview were quite different).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: MSDN]

Windows 8 / Windows 8 Pro x64 = 3.33 GiB (3,58,18,53,696 bytes) `ETA: 6.6 hrs at 1.2 Mbps`

Windows 8 / Windows 8 Pro x86 = 2.45 GiB (2,63,24,60,288 bytes) `ETA: 4.8 hrs at 1.2 Mbps`

Both the Core (normal) and Pro editions are included in one ISO. The Windows 8 setup automatically installs the edition that is available to the product key. You can also get a DVD for $20 extra.

Comment: Root: Any supporting links or screenshots for this information?

Answer (score 2):

[This source](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57541490-285/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-8/) says the installer is 2 GB. You can also shell out $20 to get it shipped to you, but that's a terrible deal.

> The ordering process happens in the installer, too. Once you've paid
>   by either credit card or PayPal, it will start downloading the 2 GB
>   installer. You get a choice of installing immediately, installing
>   later, or creating a USB key or disc from which to run the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the sizes of the original iso's 32-bit should be 2.4GB while 64-bit is 3.2GB

Answer (score 1):

See [microsoft's FAQ](http://windowsupgradeoffer.com/en-US/Home/Faq#FAQPage_Category1Question11Literal.Text) about downloaded upgrade:

[image]